# No error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: asp.net, excel

My application uses windows authentication. user login with their username/password and upload an excel sheet.
The issues is while uploading the excel ,one user able to upload the excel file but another user get an error:

```
No error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)
```

The code is same. I don't know what's the actual problem is? Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but can you check:

1. The user has permissions on the folder where the excel is uploaded.
2. If you are using OleDBCommand, and the file name is invalid then too you might get same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
// User was neither granted nor denied read access.
// Pass the callback method the integer
/// value of E_FAIL.
hr = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
```

This is how the implementation of return value usually goes. The comment may point you the possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Only Temporary solution:-** 1) If you try to upload same file name multiple times this problem will raise. So try to upload distinct file name every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem now got the solutions,

## 1 => **Timeout**

(try to insert or update part by part)

## 2 => **Cannot Overwrite**

if you trying to create a sheet with same name...